# Lyx Beamer presentations error ( \lyxframeend)

Tags: beamer, lyx

I am trying to write my thesis presentation with Beamer on Lyx , but i have an issue which is driving me crazy..

When i add a section/part or something else i get this error :

```
    \lyxframeend
                 {}\section*{fghfgh}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

I also attache a screenshot in order to understand my issue :

[image]

Any ideas please ?

Comment: I think this is improved in LyX 2.1 (to be released "soon").

Comment: If you are using Ubuntu and want to test it out (it is quite stable now and can be installed alongside your current version of LyX), use the LyX [PPA](http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/LyXOnUbuntu#toc3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LyX is being a bit silly, I think.

It seems that the custom macros LyX use, `\lyxframe` and `\lyxframeend`, are only defined if you manually add *BeginFrame* and *EndFrame* to your document, from the drop down-menu in the top left. The problem occurs because LyX automatically adds an `\lyxendframe` first, when you add a section, but without adding the definition of `\lyxendframe`. Hence, you have to, at some point, add an *EndFrame* to your document to avoid this error.

Comment: thanks a lot !! That did work :)
I have also an other issue on how to put section/title on each frame , because when i select from drop down menu section .. it does not appear :(

Comment: @ALdaperan That is quite normal, the default `beamer` theme doesn't add section/subsection names, only frametitles. You should ask a separate question about that though, it is a completely different problem. (I don't know the answer anyway.) Also, please consider accepting my answer, to mark the question as answered.